# How to detach a sql server 2008 database that is not in database list?

Tags: sql-server-2008, security

I installed sql server 2008 on windows 7 then i create a Database! after 2 days, i reinstall the windows and install the sql server! now i am trying to attach my database file, but i encounter to bellow error. i think that the files are like a attached file and i can't attach them. what is difference of an attached file and a not attached file? how can i to attach this file? Please Help Me.

Error Text:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Attach database failed for Server 'AMIR-PC'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.1600.1+((KJ_RTM).100402-1540+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Attach+database+Server&LinkId=20476
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> Unable to open the physical file "F:\Company.mdf". Operating system
>   error 5: "5(Access is denied.)". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5120)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.1600&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=5120&LinkId=20476

Comment: Crossposted - http://serverfault.com/questions/403413/how-to-detach-a-sql-server-2008-database-that-is-not-in-database-list

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure the problem is that due to the uninstall/reinstall of SQL Server, the database engine no longer has permissions on the database files.

If you move the .mdf and .ldf files to the data folder that you specified on install, it should work for you. If you want to keep the files where they are, make sure the permissions are configured to allow appropriate access to the database engine service account group.

Comment: Ok..
Very Very GooooooooooooD!
Thanks A Lot for your answer!
I moved Th .mdf & .ldf databases File To "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER2\MSSQL\DATA" Folder And I Successed to attach the Files!
But i dont know how to change database engine permision To Attach the files without moving!
How To Change Permision for allow access my database file?

Comment: @Amir: See here: http://superuser.com/questions/194365/how-can-i-change-permissions-for-the-folder-including-subfolders

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and the solution was to Run SSMS as Administrator.  I blogged about it [here](http://dotnet-programming-solutions.blogspot.com/2012/10/attach-database-encountered-operating.html).

Comment: We don't appreciate multiple widespread answers like this. If you want to link to your blog, that's fine, but the answer should be substantive and should stand on its own. I'm removing duplicate posts because they aren't helpful as-is.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error, your database is not connected and is therefore not in the list of databases on your server instance. And since it is not initially attached, it cannot be detached.

The account your SQL Server instance is running under does not have the file system permissions to access the data file that you are trying to attach. You must change the permissions on the data file before you can attach this database.